# How to generate repeated header patten by reading header-input from a file?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, join, append

Suppose I have a file that has the following unique headerline.

`block   values    Alfa    Beta    Gamma`

I want to create a table-header after reading this file. **The problem is that the number of columns starting at `Alfa` represents the sample. So, there may be any number of samples when reading different files of this kind. **

The other files could have header as:

`block   values    Alfa    Beta   Gamma   Delta    Theta`

**with the following script:**

```
my_file = open('data.txt', 'r')
for lines in my_file.read().split('\n'):
    header = lines.split('\t')
    sample = header[2::]
    with open("new_file.txt", "w") as output:
        output.write("block\t" + '\t'.join(sample))
        output.close()
```

When I have header-input as:

`block   values    Alfa    Beta    Gamma`

I get the header-output as:

`block   Alfa    Beta   Gamma`

**But, I want my output header to be:**

`block   values    Alfa_a    Alfa_b    Beta_a    Beta_b   Gamma_a    Gamma_b`

**So/And, if there are 5 samples in the header in any other input-file, I want the header-output to be:**

Header-input:

`block   values    Alfa    Beta   Gamma   Delta    Theta`

Header-output:

`block   values    Alfa_a    Alfa_b    Beta_a    Beta_b   Gamma_a    Gamma_b    Delta_a    Delta_b    Theta_a    Theta_b`

**So, the script should be able to generate the header in this format (pattern) for each samples in the input file.**

Any other solutions appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code fragment that (I think) does what you want:

```
input_lines = ["block   values    Alfa    Beta    Gamma", "block   values    Alfa    Beta   Gamma   Delta    Theta"]

for input_line in input_lines:
    header = input_line.split()
    new_header = header[:2]
    for head in header[2:]:
        new_header.append(head + "_a")
        new_header.append(head + "_b")
    print("\t".join(new_header))
```